# How do I make FontBook display a preview of the fonts which show up as a boxed question marks?

Tags: install, font, font-book

In FontBook, a lot of my installed fonts display as a boxed question mark.
How do I resolve this issue?

macOS High Sierra

[image]

Comment: Can downvotes be accompanied by a comment so I can make the question better or better understand what is wrong with it? Downvoting doesn't make you a good communicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'question mark in a box' glyph shows that the glyphs are missing from that font.

First, make sure that the preview text has not been altered to something outside the range of that font. (It's usually the pangram 'The quick brown fox...', but it may be [possible to change it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113192/how-to-show-custom-previews-for-all-fonts-in-10-9-font-book).)

If you think that the font does, or should contain those glyphs, check that you can access them in a text app.

It's possible the font cache has got corrupted. You can empty the font cache by booting to Safe Boot mode (hold down SHIFT at restart), and then restart normally.

Some third-party fonts don't always work properly, and cause oddities in terms of naming, grouping,  and other issues, if they haven't been created entirely properly.

Comment: Booting in safe mode and restarting worked - thank you so much!